# Using ScrollController to fetch pages of data doesn't update GridView with updated list

Tags: flutter, dart

When the Artworks screen is first rendered, it makes an async call that fetches the first page of data and then displays it in a grid. In the initState() function, I also add a scroll listener that fetches the next available page of data when the user reaches the bottom of the screen. The fetching logic works just fine, but the GridView doesn't seem to be rebuilt with the newly enhanced list despite calling setState(). Any ideas on why that is?

Artworks screen:

```
class Artworks extends StatefulWidget {
  const Artworks({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ArtworksState();
}

class _ArtworksState extends State<Artworks> {
  AlbumCubit get _cubit => context.read<AlbumCubit>();
  List<Photo> get artworks => _cubit.artworks;
  final ArtworkRepository _artworkRepository = getIt<ArtworkRepository>();
  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
  int _totalArtworkPages = 0;
  int _currentPage = 0;
  bool fetchedFirstPage = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller.addListener(() async {
      if (_controller.position.atEdge) {
        final bool isTop = _controller.position.pixels == 0;
        if (!isTop) {
          // scrolled to the bottom, fetch new page if available
          if (_currentPage < _totalArtworkPages - 1) {
            await _artworkRepository.getSavedArtworks(page: ++_currentPage);
            setState(() {});
          }
        }
      }
    });

    initData();
  }

  Future<void> initData() async {
    _totalArtworkPages =
        await _artworkRepository.getSavedArtworks(page: _currentPage);
    setState(() {
      fetchedFirstPage = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (!fetchedFirstPage)
        ? Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const <Widget>[
                CircularProgressIndicator(color: AppColors.red),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Loading artworks',
                  style: montserratMedium14,
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        : GridView.builder(
            controller: _controller,
            itemCount: _artworkRepository.savedArtworks.length,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              crossAxisSpacing: 4,
              mainAxisSpacing: 4,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final Photo artwork = _artworkRepository.savedArtworks[index];

              return ArtworkItem(artwork: artwork);
            },
          );
  }
}

class ArtworkItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ArtworkItem({Key? key, required this.artwork}) : super(key: key);

  final Photo artwork;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () =>
          NavigatorUtils.goToArtworkViewScreen(context, artworkId: artwork.id),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          color: AppColors.grey,
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            placeholder: (context, url) => const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: AppColors.red,
              ),
            ),
            errorWidget: (context, url, dynamic error) =>
                const Icon(Icons.error),
            imageUrl: artwork.thumbnailPhoto ?? artwork.firebasePhoto,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ArtworksRepositoryImpl:

```
class ArtworkRepositoryImpl implements ArtworkRepository {
  ArtworkRepositoryImpl({required DioClient dioClient}) : _client = dioClient;

  final DioClient _client;

  final String baseUrl = getIt<AppRepository>().env == Env.staging //
      ? stagingUrl
      : productionUrl;

  final ArtistRepository artistRepository = getIt<ArtistRepository>();

  @override
  String? token;

  @override
  List<Photo> savedArtworks = [];

  @override
  Future<int> getSavedArtworks(
      {int page = 0, int pageSize = 20, bool ascendent = true}) async {
    try {
      final ApiResponse response = await _client.httpCall(
        baseUrl: baseUrl,
        path: '/mobile/artwork/list',
        httpMethod: HttpMethod.GET,
        headers: <String, dynamic>{'x-auth-token': token},
        queryParameters: <String, dynamic>{
          'p': page,
          'size': pageSize,
          'asc': ascendent
        },
      );

      final Map<String, dynamic> data = response.data;
      final List<dynamic> artworksJson = data['results'] as List<dynamic>;

      savedArtworks.addAll(
        artworksJson.map((dynamic json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList(),
      );

      savedArtworks = savedArtworks.toSet().toList(); // remove duplicates

      return data['totalPages'] as int;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it work,if you have not try you can create a function and replace wit in your listener like :

```
_controller.addListener(_onScroll);
```

then create _onScroll

```
 Future _onScroll() async{
   if (_controller.position.atEdge) {
    final bool isTop = _controller.position.pixels == 0;
    if (!isTop) {
      // scrolled to the bottom, fetch new page if available
      if (_currentPage < _totalArtworkPages - 1) {
        await _artworkRepository.getSavedArtworks(page: ++_currentPage);
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

and check the link below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eENDlIgadr4